# constructor with initialization mock in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, mocking, rhino

could not able to create a mock for

```
public MetricsProvider(IConfig configData, IMetricsLogger log)
{
    config = configData;
    logger = log;
    oracleDAL = new OracleDataAccess(config, logger);
    MetricsData = new DataCollector();
}
```

Steps I did:
Creatde a mock object for `IConfig` and `IMetricsLogger`.
I tried to call `MetricsProvider` (config , logger) but its referring *Oracle* connection and could not able to get connection or mock connection object.

Comment: Can you please describe the test you are trying to write and which dependency you want to mock?

Comment: I want to mock MetricsProvider class. which will basically reads a data from db (OracleDataAccess) and return a DataCollector as List.

Comment: Why do you want to mock it? Is it a dependency for another class that you want to test? When you test, you test a real class, you only mock its dependencies. Please describe in detail which is your real class that you want to test, what behavior do you want to test, and which dependencies you want to mock.

Comment: my mistake, I want to mock IConfig, IMetricsLogger, IOracleDataAccess. when I am trying to access MetricsProvider (config , logger), its reffering OracledataAccess as well. OracledataAccess has connection string which is actual connectionstring to database connection.

Comment: The simplest answer is that you need to inject `IOracleDataAccess` into `MetricsProvider`. However, this might not be what you really need. You are not providing enough information for a better answer.

Comment: Yes I need to inject IOracleDataAccess into MetricsProvider, but I am getting an Exception when I am trying to inject  IOracleDataAccess into MetricsProvider in Test Method.

Comment: getting An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in LoaderMetricsProvider.exe but was not handled in user code

Comment: It sounds like that exception is really the question that needs answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a perfect example of why dependency injection is beneficial.

What you want is to test `MetricsProvider`. But because `MetricsProvider` internally creates an instance of `OracleDataAccess` and `DataCollector` you can't test `MetricsProvider` without testing those classes also.

But what do those classes depend on? Do they require additional dependencies, like app.config settings that can't be seen without looking at the source code for those classes? (And what if those classes have dependencies on other classes that have more dependencies?)

And if your test fails it will be difficult to tell if the defect is in `MetricsProvider` or some unknown dependency hidden in some other class.

The way to fix it is to pass an interface to the constructor which is implemented by `OracleDataAccess`. If it that class doesn't already implement an interface you could create a new one corresponding to the existing class. Or if you only need one method, you could define a more specific interface and wrap `OracleDataAccess` in a class that implements that interface.

Then `MetricsProvider` will depend on an interface injected into the constructor which you'll be able to mock. Since that mock will enable you to determine exactly how `IOracleDataAccess` behaves, now you'll be able to test `MetricsProvider` in isolation.